# playframework can not find conf file in production

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I'm using play 2.3.1 with hikaricp.

`activator run` works fine.
But when I execute standalone application, it shows an error that can not find dataSource.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: one of either dataSource or dataSourceClassName must be specified
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:683)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:75)
....
```

So I create `conf` directory in `%APP_HOME/bin` and move `hikaricp.properties` to `%APP_HOME/bin/conf` from `%APP_HOME/conf`,
then finally it works!

How can I fix this problem?

[UPDATED]

#### application.conf

```
dbplugin=disabled
db.default.hikaricp.file="conf/hikaricp.properties"
ebean.default="models.*"
```

#### hikaricp.properties

```
driverClassName=org.sqlite.JDBC
jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlite:lina.db

connectionInitSql=SELECT 1
connectionTestQuery=SELECT 1

# 15 minutes
maxLifetime=900000
# 5 minutes
idleTimeout=300000

maximumPoolSize=20
minimumIdle=5
```

Comment: Can you show your application.conf (the db configuration part)?

Comment: @Salem Sure. I updated it. Thanks!

Comment: The conf file is probably linked to the app with a relative directory.